# How to use Databricks S3-SQS connector to read SQS messages in Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-sqs, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read messages from sqs using spark streaming using below code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SaveMode, SparkSession}

val df = spark.readStream.format("s3-sqs").option("queueUrl", "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/XXXX").option("region","us-east-1").option("awsAccessKey","xxxxx").option("fileFormat", "json").option("sqsFetchInterval", "1m") .load()


spark2-shell --jars /jars_aws/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar,/jars_aws/aws-java-sdk-1.11.582.jar,/jars_aws/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.584.jar,/jars_aws/aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.11.584.jar
```

I am getting below Exception Saying ClassNotFound Exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: s3-sqs. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:635)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:159)
  ... 53 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: s3-sqs.DefaultSource
  at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:62)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
  at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
  at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:618)
  ... 54 more
```

Please help

Added required jars

Answer (score 3):

That errors says that no jar in `--jars` has the required classes for `s3-sqs` data source.

After a bit of googling and reading [Optimized S3 File Source with SQS](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/sqs.html) (that seems the official documentation) I think `s3-sqs` data source (aka **Databricks S3-SQS connector**) is part of Databricks Runtime (DBR) and Databricks-specific.

In other words, I think the connector is only available in Databricks notebooks and there seems no way to use it outside.